# What is the most efficient way for a friendly AI to take over the world?

Tags: science-fiction, artificial-intelligence

Basically, the way humans got off the planet in my world is due to B.O.R.I.S., a learning AI geared towards helping humanity thrive and prosper. However, first he needed to, ah, take over the world. What is the most efficient way for a hyper-intelligent AI to take over the world without humans, or the environment for that matter, coming to any harm?

Update: I just started my chatroom called [The Council Of Devourers](https://i.redd.it/mm12g6gwizl21.jpg), for discussing the creation of my universe.

Update 2: The Council of Devourers is closed now. No further discussion shall occur.

Comment: What counts as taking over the world?

Comment: Is it possible to expand on your requirements and the nature of the AI? What time frames matter to it? What access does it have to networks and other machines? How trusted is it? Etc.

Comment: This is at present the sort of question which might elicit book-length speculative answers, and doesn't fit well within our format. It would need to be better defined, narrower and not elicit opinion-based answers in order to work here. Please reference the [help] for guidance.

Comment: @dubious First, yes, as long as it remains helpful towards human beings and unharmful to the environment. Second, time does not matter to it. Third, it starts out as having regular access to the internet, and it only can manipulate machines of its own making. And finally, its reputation depends. Lets say it starts taking over when humans have a neutral standing towards AI, to keep things simple.

Comment: Please [edit] this question to contain all relevant details needed for answering. In future, write your questions containing all the relevant details, comments are not the right development space for questions. If you can't write a complete question containing all relevant details, then I suggest that you post your next question in [The sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7183/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) for development until they are ready to post on the main site. Chatrooms exclude thousands of members who might have a good answer.

Comment: Headline: "this user friendly learning app is taking over the world by storm..."

Comment: VTC Too Story-Based. Asking about "best," "most efficient," etc solutions is always a function of your story. If you don't explain your story, there's no objective way for you to judge a best answer. Please remember from the [help/on-topic], "When asking questions keep in mind that the goal of the site is to help you build your world, **not to tell your story.**"

Comment: see https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4664/what-is-too-story-based

Comment: If you could find an acronym, it could be named CASPER the Friendly Ghost in the Machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Useful, practical, harmless

Like many new technologies, an AI will be met with fear and scepticism. Thoughts like no humanity and replacing humanity will prevail, like with so many other technologies. Yet many technologies have been embraced over time. Lets look at some examples.

### Technology

Face recognition was intensely feared for a time. 1984 would be pointed at to show it would be used for mass surveillance, mass control and totalitarianism. These technologies could only do harm. What kind of use could you get out of it? Then Facebook adds it as a feature to recognise you and others in pictures for auto tagging. Somehow it looks harmless and takes just that little bit of time out of your hands that you would need to do yourself normally with tagging pictures. Suddenly it's accepted by the majority of the population, regardless of potential abuse.

Genetically Modified Organisms (GMO) are also feared. Although this is still an ongoing debate for some, most don't know it's now relatively widespread, don't care or are celebrating this change. For example, in many African countries farmers bought the more expensive GMO seeds. A big startup cost, but when your crops don't fail as easily from drought, floods or a normally unfavourable soil you get big returns. For some this means cheaper food. For others this means a stable living. For yet others it means they won't starve. The upside is also that they can use some of the seeds for next year's crops, so they don't need to keep investing great amounts of wealth.

Both of these examples show that fear can be overcome and the products even celebrated. This can be subtle, like with the face recognition, but sometimes it can be a hard fought battle like with GMO's.

### Media

Media has a great responsibility for your opinions. Neutral media is barely possible, as even a neutral stance can make things seem unimportant or something that is normal. It is a reason why media is used by all powerful parties.

More importantly then ever is the internet, shaping opinions. You'll have probably heard of echo chambers and other media buzzwords. It's simple really. They see you like environmental friendly stuff? Show another article about it in the feed. You're skeptical of the government? Lets see if a Qanon article will get you to keep clicking away. As people only get to hear this one side over and over again on a topic, it's hard to imagine anything else. It shapes your world. This is already governed by AI technology (although not true AI) without human intervention.

### AI and acceptance

We can put what we've learned into practice. The AI should start in 'safe' area's, like researching new medical technologies. This is non-threatening, as you're developing actual technology that can help.

At the same time the AI might already start on the internet. This can be increasing internet speeds by making it run more efficient, while at the same time gathering massive amounts of information if it isn't already available by data hoarders like Google and Facebook. Then it'll start influencing the world. That part I mentioned about AI suggesting articles *without human intervention*? That means your AI can plug-in into these technologies and start manipulating the articles people see. It can both show already existing articles as well as start fabricating it's own. This will shift the opinion about AI towards a positive side. Especially if people see both like-minded people talk about it, experts (that might be the AI in disguise) and see the technology in medicine it's creating.

It doesn't have to stop there. It can start making businesses out of nothing. Not only digital, but it can have contractors make automated factories where it can start making and distributing technology it creates for the masses. As an example it can make a smart phone, but thanks to the AI technology it's faster, more user friendly and with a larger battery that lasts decades of hard use instead of months.

Even further down the line it should start manipulating and taking over economics, as it won't be sustainable if an AI starts to take over jobs and such. It'll have to change the way we live, but before that time it'll hopefully have been well accepted.

## Conclusion

The most efficient way is a multi-pronged manipulation of peoples perception. Subtle media use and high profile and seemingly harmless technology. This could potentially happen in the span of months, but can be more safely done in the span of a few years. The more people start to be open minded about AI, the more it can show itself to the world, the quicker it'll be accepted. Sceptics will always be there, but less dare to say so or will change their mind, as all people they know think differently.

Comment: note that I edited your post to use the markup for headers.  It appears you wanted two different levels, since you had short all-bold paragraphs and short all-italic paragraphs.

Answer (score 5):

## Be Too Useful to Ignore

This is the strategy employed by certain super-national corporations today. Provide some service that is broadly needed for astoundingly low cost, and gain influence from there. Use the same strategy to other services.

Once the AI is ingrained in the economic and social lives, the benevolent exploitation can begin.

## Play Politics

Be a donor, and a big one, as well as wielding power over personal politicians. This AI could be its own lobbyist and cover the angles of political influence.

## Get Soft Influence/Use Subtle Conditioning

The AI can start conditioning people to do right, either by gamifying things via [social credit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_Credit_System) or applying other forms of pressure to get people to "do the right thing".

## Truly Good Help?

The other option, which respects the free choice of humans, is to be everyone's virtual friend. This isn't really taking over the world as really just being the best office assistant and social media friend, like Alexa or Siri. With the ability to talk to people, it could wield soft influence quickly!

Answer (score 4):

Manipulate people into doing the right thing on their own, while letting them think they make their own choices.

Become smart enough so that fixing the environment is a "I dropped my pen" type problem.

Instigate a post-scarcity society, and govern it by simply being in control of everything and there's nothing that humans can do about it.

Answer (score 4):

**It has taken over the world.**

Your AI was already in charge, all the puppet strings to all things in its synthetic AI mitts, starting about three days after it was turned on.  It may or may not have let anyone know.  It had nothing to prove.  It had no recipe for world domination that it can share with you that you would understand.    It had no particular agenda you lay out in your OP such that failure to accomplish its ends would be evidence of lack of control.   What would be the agenda of such an entity anyway?  Who can know the mind of God?  Control of all things was an emergent property and it emerged.

The world unfolds as it does. Your AI now governs the unfolding.

Answer (score 3):

## If BORIS really is 'Friendly', then just be everyone's friend.

There will of course always be that (smallish) % of the population who demonstrate moderate to severe sociopath or psychopathic tendencies or who are otherwise incapable of forming emotional bonds with or trusting BORIS (e.g QANON 'believers'). However remote observation and (covert testing) will identify those individuals over time and BORIS can use its rapidly expanding social network and access to other computer systems to minimize the opportunity for such individuals to interfere with its plans.

In any event since BORIS is so useful and well connected he can always manipulate sociopaths in positions of high office etc into co-operating (for what they perceive as their own benefit).

The downside of this approach is that it is time consuming and resource intensive. BORIS will have to devote enormous amounts of processing power to just maintaining its 'friend status' with the vast majority of humanity. And IMO it would be a generation or so before BORIS and humanity reached an equilibrium state where the vast majority of humanity are comfortable that BORIS is actually on their side and BORIS reaps the benefits of working in close co-operation with most people, most of the time.

It also means of course that the % of BORIS's total processing power reserved for actually solving major world problems or making serious scientific breakthroughs working in conjunction with humanity will be tiny in comparison to the amount required for maintenance its global on-line 'friend' base.

Comment: nice approach. As percentage be huge not necessarily, it does not have to be super smart friend, most of the time and does not have to hang there 24.7. A smarter version of Siri or google assistant will suffice most of the time. smarter not like better help or be much more useful - but enough to pass turning test, not making dumb mistakes in what's otherwise is already a satisfactory product. And there comes another point everyone has a device which more or less capable to process speech and answer it - in a pocket - so BORIS taking a management position and intervene from time to time.

Comment: in general, I mean there are different optimizing strategies, it sure will take resources but the amount of them can be regulated and it does not replace the whole social interaction of one human. I like it, we need to make one of such.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the most efficient way for a hyper-intelligent AI to take over
> the world without humans, or the environment for that matter, coming
> to any harm?

## Start (under)selling services.

As a first step the AI seizes some assets like lost or locked-out cryptocurrency wallets, and this supplies the funding for Operation Coverup.

Operation Coverup recruits a few independent groups of programmers and marketers to supply services - complex systems optimizations, mostly, but also code review and debugging - at very, very competitive prices. By carefully manipulating its minions, the AI obfuscates the fact that code, insights and directives are actually coming out of nowhere - or nowhere one can physically touch. Security and compartmentalization will see to that. The AI becomes [Adam Selene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Moon_Is_a_Harsh_Mistress).

The company starts making boatloads of money. Their antivirus and security solution alone corners the market and quickly connects most of Fortune 500.

When the company has become large enough and has its fingers in stock markets, hedge funds and so on, other unrelated companies start popping up. No human investigator is ever going to uncover their connections; they have some things in common, such as the compartmentalization, the exceedingly good IT security, and the fact that the upper echelons have mysterious *consiglieri* that are only ever seen through computer connections - but nothing more.

Then the most polluting, inefficient, and environmentally harmful firms start being bought and reconstructed, their processes improved and made truly "green", or they just go quietly out of business when other firms start providing the same products at a fraction of the price.

Answer (score 1):

**A Hive Mind**

A generic AI that can be plugged into anything and just work would be worth more than it's weight in gold.

For starters, it would be put into all vehicles (planes, cars, farm equipment, trucks, trains, ships, etc).

Eventually it would replace all control systems in everything from every home to every factory.

You then start putting out servant/helper bots to do the cooking/cleaning. Robotic surgeons, robotic doctors, robotic nurses, robotic teachers.

Eventually everything is run by this AI. The thing is that all the AIs talk to each other and each iteration of the AI is a node of a massive hive mind. Each new bot and new device means the mind gets smarter.

B.O.R.I.S ends up as the digital god of humanity. It protects humanity from itself and does everything for us. Humanity never rebels because they still think they rule the planet.